# Retrieve line number of string in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

I'm trying to retrieve the line number of a given string in the text displayed in the ace editor.

1. Example: searching for "foo"
2. Return: [ 4, 5 ]
3. Condition: Line 4 and 5 in the content of the ace editor contains the "foo" string

Comment: Good luck, let us know.

Comment: @Virus721 no ideas? :D why good luck? do you think it's close to impossible?

Comment: If you can retrieve the full content of the editor, you can split it by `\n` and then search the string using `indexOf`. If `result > -1` then you add the current `i+1`(since you're looping the result of the split, which is an array) to the `line` array. The only problem is that I don't know if(and how) you can get the content of the Ace Editor

Comment: According to the [docs(see common operations)](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto), you can use `editor.getValue()` to retrieve the code.

Comment: I tried it by splitting at the linebreaks using \n but this seems to be very inefficient to me ... wish there would be a better solution :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate over all lines and check indexOf

```
function findFooLineNumbers(editor, foo) {
    var lines = editor.session.doc.getAllLines()
    var fooLineNumbers = []
    for (var i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (lines[i].indexOf(foo) != -1)
           fooLineNumbers.push(i)
    }
    return fooLineNumbers
}
```

Comment: This is how I did it now, yeah ... thought there might be a more efficient way ... or at least a way to do it thought the ace API

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
var found = editor.$search.find(editor.getSession());
```

More on this on https://www.debugcn.com/en/article/12331736.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
editor.session.getLength()
```

Answer (score -1):

You left too little information and you can not expect a great help

If you want to return more information at the same time u need **Array**

```
var number = new Number(5) // Single number. he will return just 5
```

You can try somthing like this to see how to return array

```
function test() {
    var IDs = new Array();
        IDs['s'] = "1 342 364,586";
        IDs['g'] = "123 324 646 876";

        for (var i = 0; i <= IDs.lenght; i ++ ) {
             // do somthing  
        }
    return IDs;
}
```

To check if return is realy nubmer use  **Number.NaN**

Comment: How is this referred to the question?

Comment: If u read question he want return line of numbers. If u know better common post.

Comment: If you read the question you would have seen that he wants the line of the code inside an Ace Editor. I repeat my question: **how is this related to the question?**

Comment: So u want to say all editors have diferent java script? OK i repeat self. If u know post question dont troll me. I try to help

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. Please read it carefully again.

Comment: LOL, how the hell does this have anything to do with ace. Sorry man, you did not get the question.