# how to retrieve a line of text from ACE editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, text-extraction

I integrated ACE editor in my site. I want to retrieve the text in a certain line. I've searched and found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906120/ace-editor-get-current-selected-line-number-and-text) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013109/retrieve-line-number-of-string-in-ace-editor). But unfortunately, I can't understand those, as I'm a newbie to the subject. **Can anyone give an example for it ?**
I got the lines to an array using the following code.

```
var line = document.getElementsByClassName("ace_line");
```

Are there any methods like

```
line[count].getValue
```

Which can return the string of the text in that line ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call

```
line0 = editor.session.getLine(0);
```

using `getElementsByClassName("ace_line")` or similar won't work since

1. ace creates DOM elements only for visible lines.
2. text content of the DOM element is different from the text in document since tabs and some other characters are replaced by spaces.

Comment: He asked how to get it from the NodeList, while he might be *asking the wrong question*, this isn't an answer to his question. I agree, he should do this of course but he linked to an answer identical to this already in his question.

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge that answer only seems to work, try scrolling the editor and lines will become wrong.

Comment: @someDoge this is not identical, this answer explains why NodeList can't work.  Your answer is wrong since it advises him to get a wrong value of a wrong line.

Comment: This is identical to an answer *already linked in his question*. Please re-read it and click his links. I'm not claiming my answer does anything but explain how to use a NodeList. Notice the `if` at the start of my answer, I don't think I need to explain what a condition is to a programmer.

Comment: @auser ah, got your point. Thanx. I will use this method. Thank both of you.

Comment: @someDoge i am only trying to explain that 1. he can't have all lines in a nodelist, 2. lineNode.textContent is different from line in the document.

Comment: He *can* have all the lines in a NodeList, but he *likely doesn't* ;). Anyway I can't delete an accepted answer. @ThisaruGuruge please accept this answer or another.

Answer (score 0):

`line[count]` already returns the DOM element of that line. So all you have to do is to extract the plain text from that element. if you are using jQuery you could do:

To get the text of the first line for example (`line[0]`)

```
var lineText = line[0].text();
```

If you are not using jQuery and want to do that in javascipt:

```
var lineText = line[0].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
```

Comment: What are you trying with that `replace`? You wanted `innerText` or `textContent` // textContent for compatibility. It's a NodeList

Comment: Where did I say anything about getElementsByTagName?

Comment: @SamBattat if you read his question... Anyway, this doesn't work and it's explained in the comments of the newly accepted answer.

Comment: @someDoge I did forget to include innerHTML (See update). This would work, but your solution is the ideal solution

Comment: @SamBattat Eh, it's actually another thing entirely. I deleted my answer because this method doesn't actually work